# Not being able to call a javascript function through a button

Tags: javascript

So I have this program where I update a .txt file and it shows me the content of it.
But now I want it to show me only when I click on the button.
But it´s not woking.

```
<div id="output"></div>
<button id="btn">Click me</button>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    document.getElementById("btn").addEventListener("click", function () {
        const input = document.getElementById("inputfile");
        if (!input.files.length) {
            alert("No file selected!");
            return;
        }

        const fr = new FileReader();
        fr.onload = function () {
            if (!fr.result) { 
                return;
            }
            const resultAsArray = fr.result.split('\r\n'); 
            let index = 0; 
            const displayInterval = setInterval(() => { 
                if (index === (resultAsArray.length - 1)) { 
                    clearInterval(displayInterval); 
                    return;
                }
                let html$ = document.getElementById('output').innerHTML;
                html$ += '<div>' + resultAsArray[index] + '</div>';
                document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = html$; 
                index++; 
                
            }, 1000);

        }

        fr.readAsText(this.files[0]);

    });
</script>
```

**I got this javascript code from the Internet**

Comment: There is no (named) function, it runs when the file input changes. (Also, I find myself saying this a lot, but please avoid using code you don't fully understand, it's a great way to cause yourself more problems than you're solving)

Comment: So i can I name it ? I want it to run only when I click the button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can name the function, then change to get files from input, so just replace this.files[0] to file than you get from input.

```html
<input type="file" name="inputfile" id="inputfile">
<br>

<div id="output"></div>
<button onclick="test()">Click me</button>


<script type="text/javascript">
    function test() {
        var inputElement = document.getElementById('inputfile');
        var fileList = inputElement.files;
        var fr = new FileReader();
            fr.onload = function () {
                if (!fr.result) { 
                    return;
                }
                const resultAsArray = fr.result.split('\r\n'); 
                let index = 0; 
                const displayInterval = setInterval(() => { 
                    if (index === (resultAsArray.length - 1)) {
                        clearInterval(displayInterval); 
                        return;
                    }
                    let html$ = document.getElementById('output').innerHTML;
                    html$ += '<div>' + resultAsArray[index] + '</div>'; 
                    document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = html$; 
                    index++; 

                }, 1000);

            }
            fr.readAsText(fileList[0]);
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Didn´t worked.,

Comment: @JoãoSantos i've make some modifications, can you try again? if i helped you, can you mark this question as solved?

Answer (score 1):

Try doing this:

Wherever you're doing the HTML Stuff:

```
<button id="button-id">Click Me</button>
```

Then, inside your JavaScript:

```
let button = document.getElementById('button-id')
button.addEventListener("click", theFunction);

function theFunction() {
//Code to be executed when the button is pressed..
}
```

Comment: I got your point but it is not working.

Comment: Then it could even be an error from the JavaScript you have gotten from the Internet.

 Or maybe put your script inside <script> //code </script>

Answer (score 0):

Give an id to button then use this code.

```
    document.getElementById('buttonID')
        .addEventListener('click', function (){
   //statements
})
```

Comment: Hmmmm, this answer almost deserves an upvote but it's a bit lazy. Providing the corresponding HTML code instead of saying "Give an id to button" would be so much better.

Comment: I´ve done it bue It didn´t worked.
<button  id="buttonID">Click me</button>
        document.getElementById('buttonID')
            .addEventListener('click', function ()  {